# jooq results don't mapped by RecordMapperProvider

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jooq

I use spring boot with jooq and kotlin to develop my web application. i added a RecodMapperProvider to replace "<EmptyString>" by null in result objects. my mapper is :

```
import org.jooq.*
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration
import org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType

class EmptyStringToNullRecordMapperProvider : RecordMapperProvider {
    override fun <R : Record?, E : Any?> provide(recordType: RecordType<R>?, type: Class<out E>?): RecordMapper<R, E> {
        val originalMapper = DefaultConfiguration().recordMapperProvider().provide(recordType, type)


        // Return a custom record mapper that replaces "EMPTYSTRING" values with null
        return RecordMapper { record ->

            originalMapper.map(record).apply {
                recordType?.fields()?.forEach { field ->
                    if (field.dataType.sqlDataType == SQLDataType.VARCHAR) {
                        System.out.println(record);
                        val originalValue = record?.getValue(field) as String?
                        if ("<EmptyString/>" == originalValue) {
                            record?.setValue(field, null)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i load data from config table and try to replace  by null. my repository is like this:

```
import fr.test.model.jooq.generated.tables.records.*
import fr.test.model.jooq.generated.tables.references.CONFIG
import org.jooq.DSLContext
import org.jooq.Record1
import org.jooq.Record2
import org.jooq.impl.DSL.arrayAgg
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import java.util.stream.Stream

@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class LiveConfigurationRepository
(
        @Autowired
        private val jooq: DSLContext
) {
    fun getConfiguration(): Map<String, List<String>> {
        val rawData: MutableMap<String, List<String>> = mutableMapOf()

        jooq.dsl().select(CONFIG)
                .from(CONFIG)
                .fetch()
                .stream()
                .forEach { record ->
                    run {
                        val mapData = record.intoMap();
                        val configRecord: ConfigRecord = mapData["config"] as ConfigRecord;

                        val key: String = configRecord.key!!
                        val value: String? = configRecord.value
                        if (!value.isNullOrBlank())
                            addValueToMap(rawData, key, value);
                    }
                }

        return rawData;


    }

    fun addValueToMap(rawData: MutableMap<String, List<String>>, key: String, value: String) {
        if (rawData.containsKey(key)) {
            val existingList = rawData[key]!!.toMutableList()
            existingList.add(value)
            rawData[key] = existingList
        } else {
            rawData[key] = listOf(value)
        }
    }
```

There are many results that didn't treated by the mapperProvider and in my rawData i find result with  i can't find why.
Can any one has an idea about the problem?

Thank's!

i tried to debug but i can't see the problem

Answer (score 0):

[`RecordMapperProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/RecordMapperProvider.html) is an SPI that helps override the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html). Its purpose is to map between a jOOQ `Result` of any type and custom target types via reflection, e.g. when you call `result.into(MyType::class.java)`

A lot of results aren't mapped by this `RecordMapper`, though, in case of which you still get the original behaviour. In general, you're not really looking for a `RecordMapper` but for a [`Converter`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Converter.html) or a [`Binding`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Binding.html), which you can [attach to generated code](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/). That way, every jOOQ query will use your conversion logic (possibly two way!) to make sure you'll never get an `""` anymore.

Another option that is possible in your case, since you seem to want to remove `""` from *all* of your results would be to proxy JDBC directly. jOOQ has a [`DefaultConnection`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/DefaultConnection.html) that can help you with the implementation. Just override the [`DefaultResultSet::getString`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/DefaultResultSet.html#getString(int)) method and similar methods.